# How to compare Dates with JPA when DataBase has different format to java.sql.Date

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I hope you are very well.

Right now, I am working a project in **JAVA** which uses *Spring Framework* and ***JPA repositories***.

Like it is normal, I am trying to get information from a table be means the following **JPA** method:

```
Optional<Car> = findByNameAndModelDtIsLessThanEqual(String name, Java.sql.Date modelDt);
```

Where entity **Car** has the following definition:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer carId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "model_dt")
    private Date modelDt;

        //Getters and Setters
}
```

when I am debugging the code, the argument in the method are:

```
name: "VW"
modelDT: '2020-03-02'
```

However the **JPA** query is not working, because in the database the **model_dt** field appears with the  **"dd-MON-yy"** format ("02-MAR-20") and the [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) has other format (**"yyyy-mm-dd"**).

I have tried to replace `java.sql.Date` **modelDt** by String **modelDt** in the definition repository (with the intention to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class), However, it has not worked of this way.

I would like to know if there is one way to compare Dates from JPA (I would like to avoid using JPQL).

Does someone know how can I solve this.

Regards.

Comment: In these cases, you can use the JPA `AttributeConverter` interface https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html. It allows converting types before and after the mapping, in your case could be helpful in order to operate with the same type. There are samples https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters and here https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: As a comment, if you are formatting dates, try to use the `DateTimeFormatter` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class instead of the `SimpleDateFormat`, because the last one isn't thread-safe.

Comment: BTW, you are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. The *java.time* classes are supported in both JPA and Hibernate.

Comment: another option would be to use criteriaBuilder.function("to_date", DATE_VAR, "yyyyMMdd")